# How do I pass a copy constructor as a method reference?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, copy-constructor, method-reference

I have a class PlanItemEditor.

I require the E item's copy constructor. How do I pass it in using a method reference?

```
public void initValues(ObservableList<E> srcList, E toEdit) {
    indexToSet = srcList.indexOf(toEdit);
    editing = new E(toEdit);
    this.srcList = srcList;
}
```

I was thinking of including a Unary function as a parameter, and passing in a method from the E class that was exactly a copy constructor, but with a different name signature. It's kind of hacky, however.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What you describe sounds to me like a [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) method and that is a legit means of creating an instance.

Comment: Don't forget to make another factory for the AbstractFactoryBean that'll create your factory!

Comment: I agree with fildor. Depending on your needs, no need for a full on factory. You can simply add a static method for createInstance on your class that takes in another instance as a param. You will have to modify your generics declaration accordingly where necessary.

Comment: A constructor is not really a method, it's a special kind of thing of its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
public void initValues(ObservableList<E> srcList, E toEdit, UnaryOperator<E> copy) {
    indexToSet = srcList.indexOf(toEdit);
    editing = copy.apply(toEdit);
    this.srcList = srcList;
}
```

And you can call it with:

```
initValues(srcList, toEdit, YourClass::new);
```

Comment: But doesn't ::new refer to the default ctor?

Comment: @Tonimiko it depends on the type of the argument in `initValues`. In this case it is a `UnaryOperator<E>` so it expects a method or constructor that accepts one argument of type E. If you change the signature of `initValues` to `..., Supplier<E> ctor)` then `YourClass::new` will refer to a no-arg constructor.

Comment: I see. Is it smart enough to differentiate between many telescoping constructors too, then?

Comment: @Tonimiko: it’s the same as with method references. The right one will be chosen from the context.

Comment: @Tonimiko Yes it is that smart :)  The assignment context (in this case, the method argument type) provides a target type, which here is E->E; it uses this combination of argument/return types to perform ordinary method overload resolution on the named method, just like with a method call.